# How to remove celery task ?

Tags: django, django-celery

I practice `django-celery`

settings.py

```
#import datetime
#CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
#    'hello_task': {
#        'task': 'hello_task',
#        'schedule': datetime.timedelta(seconds=20),
#    },
#}

import datetime
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'add-every-30-seconds': {
        'task': 'app1.tasks.myfunc',
        'schedule': datetime.timedelta(seconds=30),
    },
}
```

I try `hello_task` schedule at first,then I commented it  and try `add-every-30-seconds`

But it still want to execute when `hello_task` time comes

So I check the database and found it was save the record int it

[image]

Why wouldn't it delete when I commented it ??
Is there any command or normal way to delete it   ???

Or If I just delete it from database is well ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the `django-celery` database scheduler those periodic tasks in `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE` dict will be added to Django's database, as you found out. django-celery's scheduler then reads its settings primarily from the database. Removing entries from the dict just means that `django-celery` has nothing to add to the database.

To delete the task properly, remove it from the Django admin page (Djcelery > Periodic Tasks).

Answer (score -1):

When you change the code that celery is working with, you should restart celery to understand the changes. Such as needing to restart django server whenever you change your python codes.

Comment: Restarting celery doesn't help here, as the code change doesn't remove the DB entry for the schedule.  After removing the DB entry from the Django admin UI, as mentioned in the answer), the change will take effect immediately.